# How to determine if top of DIV is within screen view using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, position

I have a DIV that is several hundred pixels in height. When a user clicks a button, I would like to ensure they can view the very top when the Ajax returns a second view from the server.

How can I make it so it will only scroll to the top of the DIV if the top currently isn't in view?

For example, if a user hasn't scrolled at all on the page, has a high resolution and can view the entire DIV, I don't want any scrolling to occur. For users running lower resolutions, I would like to make sure they are sent to the top of the DIV so they can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a check with a function like so

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/yhQZu/18/)**

```
function checkIfInView(element){
    var offset = element.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

    if(offset > window.innerHeight){
        // Not in view
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 1000);
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}​
```

You would call it after your ajax function on the div you want to check like so

```
checkIfInView($('#testdiv'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would require any `jQuery` at all. I would place a `id` on the top `div` and redirect to the url with the `div` name in the url, here is an example:

```
<div id="top_div"></div>
```

redirect with `js`:

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "url.com/#top_div";
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, simple and doesn't require anything fancy to get working :)